# When was the change from kalends, ides and nones to numbers

Tags: calendar

The Romans named the days of the month by counting down to kalends, ides and nones. We use numbers counting up from one for the first day of the month. When did this change take place?

I assume that it was gradual, with people using the modern system when it was the more convenient, but I can find no information about who did it, nor when it happened, except a vague reference to the Roman system being in use until the Renaissance.

Comment: It's to do with history, and with numbers, and with your interest in astronomy as well, i'd have thought it was very pertinent.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko - Counting days, livestock, and (much later) money is where mathematics started.

Comment: @David Hammen: perhaps this is where mathematics started. But change of the dates nomenclature happened at least a thousand years after mathematics started, probably more, and has nothing to do with mathematics or astronomy.

Comment: @Comintern - Yes. The mods there informed me they were migrating it here, and suggested we merge the two copies. However, since this one doesn't have any answers from that stack with it...

Comment: @T.E.D. - Wasn't sure how these were handled, so I'll leave it in your capable hands.

Comment: @Comintern - I wasn't either, but after talking with the HSM mod, I think you have the right of it.